# Split a string after some specific sub-string in Java using regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "FirstName LastName - 1234xx"
```

In above case, want to replace above string with everything after " - " substring. In the above example it would mean changing `str` to `1234xx`

The length of string after " - " is not fixed, hence cannot just capture last certain no. of characters

This approach gives `FirstName LastName -  -` instead of desired output `1234xx`

```
public class StringExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str = "FirstName LastName - 1234xx";
        String newStr = str.replaceAll("(?<=( - )).*", "$1");

        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more cases? It seems substring after '-' and trimmed all spaces is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  Just use a lazy dot to consume everything up to and including the dash.

```
String str = "FirstName LastName - 1234xx";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("^.*-\\s*", "");

System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: Thanks, one thing though. Want everything after " - " and not "-". How to include whitespaces before and after "-"? Want this test case to fail `FirstName LastName-1234xx`

Comment: Yes, [it still works with that input](https://rextester.com/OKSM83762).

Comment: Not want that case to work. Based on your answer, think this would be the right implementation `"^.*( - )\\s*", ""`. Can you verify?

Comment: `instead of desired output 1234xx` ... what is your desired output if not `1234xx`  ?

Comment: My sub-string to check would be " - " and not "-". Want those white-spaces around dash, then split substring beyound that. Input `FirstName LastName - 1234xx` should yeild `1234xx` while `FirstName LastName-1234xx` should yield same string `FirstName LastName-1234xx`.Could reach to my desired answer though. Thanks